# how to create pdf with asp.net 3.5

Tags: itext, asp.net-3.5

i'm .net developer. here i just want to create pdf report.for more info i include this code:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
        Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
            Phrase phrase = null;
            PdfPCell cell = null;
            PdfPTable table = null;
            Color color = null;

            document.Open();

            //Header Table
            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.TotalWidth = 500f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 0.7f });

            //Company Logo
            cell = ImageCell("../images/easyweb_logo.gif", 30f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.AddCell(cell);

            //Company Name and Address
            phrase = new Phrase();
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Electrocom Technology India Limited\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 16, Font.BOLD, Color.RED)));
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("712, Sukhsagar Complex,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Nr. Hotel Fortune Landmark, Ashram Road,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Ahmedabad - 380 014,", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            phrase.Add(new Chunk("Gujarat (INDIA).", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            //Separater Line
            color = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
            DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 79f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 79f, color);
            DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 80f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 80f, color);
            document.Add(table);

            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 1f });
            table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

            //Post Detail
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("\n"+"Post Record", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            table.AddCell(cell);
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 30f;
            table.AddCell(cell);


            //Name
            phrase = new Phrase();
            phrase.Add(new Chunk(dr["Title"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
            cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            table.AddCell(cell);
            document.Add(table);

            DrawLine(writer, 160f, 80f, 160f, 690f, Color.BLACK);
            DrawLine(writer, 115f, document.Top - 200f, document.PageSize.Width - 100f, document.Top - 200f, Color.BLACK);

            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.5f, 2f });
            table.TotalWidth = 340f;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

            //Title
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Title :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Title"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);


            //Description
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Description :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Description"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            //Category Name
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Category Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["CategoryName"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            //Status Name
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Status Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["StatusName"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            //Group Name
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Group Name :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["GroupName"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            //Publisher
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Publisher :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["Publisher"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            //To User
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("To User :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(dr["ToUser"] + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);


            //Publish Date
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Publish Date :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            phrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(string.Format("{0:F}", dr["PublishDate"])+"\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
            table.AddCell(PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.Colspan = 2;
            cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            document.Close();
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PostRecord.pdf");
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.End();
            Response.Close();
```

here there are only show few fields.

**-----------------------------------------Updated------------------------------------------------**

here i include my output:
[image]

tell me wat is problem in my code.

for furthure more information i include this [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-PDF-Report-from-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your code where it says:

```
table.AddCell(cell);
document.Close();
```

Now add one line like this:

```
table.AddCell(cell);
document.Add(table);
document.Close();
```

You were creating a table object, but you weren't adding it to the document.

Comment: here i have Description field that was ntext. i want to show it's original view. you know what i mean when ever to display html enabled text to original view we use Literal control.

Comment: I have no idea whet ntext, original view, html enabled text or literal control mean in this context. Can you create a new question that clarifies what you mean? I see that somebody downvoted your question. My guess: you know what you want to ask in your head, but when you type your question, you omit half of the words.

Comment: you can see my updated question. here you show that Description field content. which is [NTEXT] now i want use to html encode/decode with it and want to make original view.

Comment: You are updating a question with an accepted answer. This is not done. You should post a new question. As for your question: you are asking to *interpret* HTML. This is done with XML Worker: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D11_ParseHtmlObjects

Comment: can u give me steps how i include this with .net.